# Where's GetTickCount() in Windows 8 Consumer Preview?

Tags: c++, windows-8, winapi

I recently ported a very trivial app from Windows 8 Developer Preview to Windows 8 Consumer Preview.  Everything seems to work fine except **now** the function [`GetTickCount()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724408.aspx) no longer seems to be defined in Windows.h or WinBase.h.

Despite the fact that I have these headers defined at the top of my file:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinBase.h>
```

My code line

```
unsigned int seed = GetTickCount() % UINT_MAX;
```

still gives me the error:

```
error C3861: 'GetTickCount': identifier not found
```

Can anyone tell me where `GetTickCount()` went or what I should use as a replacement?

Comment: What about QueryPerformanceCounter()?

Comment: Including winbase.h after windows.h is redundant and does nothing.

@paulsm4: Possible replacement but it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @paulsm4 - That seems to work for me better than GetTickCount.  I appreciate this comment.  It is a workaround for my issue since all I ultimately wanted to do was seed the srand function.

Comment: @CareyGregory - I kind of figured including winbase.h after windows.h was redundant.  Thanks for confirming that for me.  Your comment should help me to understand.

Comment: If all you needed was a seed for srand, then QueryPerformanceCountry()is a better choice anyway since it has much higher resolution.  Good example of why you should ask the question you're really trying to solve rather than the narrow question you think you're trying to solve (I've done the same myself).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [`GetTickCount` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount):

> **Applies to:** desktop apps only

From the [`GetTickCount64` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/sysinfoapi/nf-sysinfoapi-gettickcount64):

> **Applies to:** desktop apps | Metro style apps

So, use `GetTickCount64`.

Comment: Looks like they're taking advantage of this to deprecate old APIs that have better alternatives. Props to MS.